# How to remove some duplicated expression using simplifying tactic in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I use the following tactic to simplify the experession

```
(apply (then  (! simplify :eq2ineq true) ctx-solver-simplify propagate-values ctx-solver-simplify (par-then (repeat (or-else split-clause skip)) propagate-ineqs) tseitin-cnf))
```

The original expression is:

```
( 0 > t_DS or 1 > t_FS or 1 > t_PS) And 
(true) And 
(( 0 > t_DS or 0 > t_FS or 0 > t_PS) or (t_DS <= 3)) And 
(( 0 > t_DS or 0 > t_FS or 0 > t_PS or t_FS <= 1) or ( t_DS+t_FS <= 3)) And
((0 > t_DS or 0 > t_PS or 1 > t_FS or t_PS > 1) or ( t_DS+t_PS <= 2)) And
(t_DS >=0) And (t_FS >= 0) And (t_PS >=0)
```

After apply the tactic, the simplified result is :

```
(goals
(goal
  (>= t_FS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_FS 1.0))
  (<= (+ t_DS t_FS) 3.0)
  (>= t_DS 0.0)
  (<= t_DS 3.0)
  (>= t_User 0.0)
  (>= t_PS 0.0))
(goal
  (>= t_FS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_FS 1.0))
  (<= (+ t_DS t_FS) 3.0)
  (>= t_DS 0.0)
  (<= t_DS 3.0)
  (not (<= t_PS 1.0))
  (>= t_User 0.0))
(goal
  (>= t_FS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_FS 1.0))
  (>= t_DS 0.0)
  (<= t_DS 2.0)
  (<= (+ t_DS t_PS) 2.0)
  (>= t_PS 0.0)
  (<= t_PS 2.0)
  (>= t_User 0.0))
(goal
  (>= t_PS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_PS 1.0))
  (not (<= t_FS 1.0))
  (<= (+ t_DS t_PS) 2.0)
  (>= t_DS 0.0)
  (<= t_DS 2.0)
  (>= t_User 0.0))
(goal
  (>= t_PS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_PS 1.0))
  (<= (+ t_DS t_FS) 3.0)
  (>= t_DS 0.0)
  (<= t_DS 3.0)
  (>= t_FS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_FS 1.0))
  (>= t_User 0.0))
(goal
  (>= t_PS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_PS 1.0))
  (<= (+ t_DS t_FS) 3.0)
  (>= t_DS 0.0)
  (<= t_DS 2.0)
  (>= t_FS 0.0)
  (<= t_FS 3.0)
  (<= (+ t_DS t_PS) 2.0)
  (>= t_User 0.0))
)
```

However, I think the second goal can be removed, since it is stronger than the first one. So how to use z3 to get the simpler result?

```
(goal
  (>= t_FS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_FS 1.0))
  (<= (+ t_DS t_FS) 3.0)
  (>= t_DS 0.0)
  (<= t_DS 3.0)
  (>= t_User 0.0)
  (>= t_PS 0.0))
(goal
  (>= t_FS 0.0)
  (not (>= t_FS 1.0))
  (<= (+ t_DS t_FS) 3.0)
  (>= t_DS 0.0)
  (<= t_DS 3.0)
  (not (<= t_PS 1.0))
  (>= t_User 0.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can't be done in the current implementation because there is no communication between different goals.